# Remove rows from multiple dataframe that contain bad data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have n `dataframes`, df1, df2...dfn.

Finding rows that contain "bad" values in a row in a given dataframe is done by e.g.,

```
index1 = df1[df1.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])]
index2 = df2[df2.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])]
```

Now, `drop`ing these bad rows in the bad `dataframe` is done with:

```
df1 = df1.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()
df2 = df2.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()
```

The problem is that any function that expects the two (n) `dataframes` `columns` to be of the same length may give an error if there is bad data in one df but not the other.

How do I drop not just the bad row from the offending `dataframe`, but the same row from a `list of dataframes`?

So in the two `dataframe` case, if in df1 date `index` 2009-10-09 contains a "bad" value, that same row in df2 will be dropped.

**[Possible "ugly"? solution?]**
I suspect that one way to do it is to `merge` the two (n) `dataframes` on date, then apply the cleanup function to drop "bad" values are automatic since the entire row gets dropped? But what happens if a date is missing from one `dataframe` and not the other? [and they still happen to be the same length?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing your `replace`

```
df1 = df1.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df2 = df2.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

Then, Here we using inner .

```
newdf=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,keys=[1,2], join='inner').dropna()
```

And split it back to two dfs  , here we using `combine_first` with `dropna` of original df

```
df1,df2=[s[1].loc[:,s[0]].combine_first(x.dropna()) for x,s in zip([df1,df2],newdf.groupby(level=0,axis=1))]
```